# Cannot do toggle in Chrome and Edge

Tags: javascript, toggle

Before migrating to Chrome and Edge, we were using IE11 for our website and it got no error. But now, IE11 is dead and must use modern browser for our website. But I found new problem that's I cannot do toggle in our website and I've checked with Developer tool and console log, found 0 error message. But, it's not working and is there anyway to fix it?

```
echo "<th class='tdHdr'>"; // export to excel image
                        echo "<img id='imgExport' src='export2excel.ico' onClick='clickExport();' alt='export to excel via csv file'/>";
                    echo "</th>";
                    echo "<th class='tdHdr'>"; // show/hide all images
                        echo "<div><img class='showicon' id='imgShow0' value='x|0' src='show.png' alt='click to show all details'/></div>";
                        echo "<div><img class='hideicon' id='imgHide0' value='x|0' src='hide.png' alt='click to hide all details'/></div>";
                    echo "</th>";
                    echo "<th class='tdHdr' style='padding-right:55px;'>";
                        echo "KPI Performance<br>Indicator";
                    echo "</th>";
```

Below is JavaScript.

```
    $(document).ready(function (){
$(".hideicon").click(function(){ //hide downtime
        var id = $(this).val();
        var dt = id.split('|');
        var sh = 'h';
        toggle(dt[0], dt[1], sh);
        //toggle(id, sh)
    });

    $(".showicon").click(function(){ //hide downtime
        var id = $(this).val();
        var dt = id.split('|');
        var sh = 's';
        toggle(dt[0], dt[1], sh);
        //toggle(id, sh)
    });
}
```

Below is function for toggle.

```
function toggle(x, y, z){
    var max = $('#subCt').val();
    if(x == 'x'){ //show/hide all
        if(z == 's'){
            var arry = $('.hideicon');
        } else {
            var arry = $('.showicon');
        }
        for(var i = 1; i < arry.length; i++){ 
            var raw = $(arry[i]).val().substr(0, 2);
            //alert(raw);
            if(z == 'h'){
                $('.'+raw+'1').hide(); // table row
                            
                $('.showicon').show(); // show icons
                $('.hideicon').hide(); // hide icons

                $('#imgShow'+y).show(); // show all icon
                $('#imgHide'+y).hide(); // hide all icon
                
                $('#body').css("height", "auto");
                $('#body').css("padding-bottom", "30px");
                $('#footerDiv').css("bottom", "0%");    
                
                openSubCategory = 0;
            } else {
                $('.'+raw+'1').show();
                
                $('.showicon').hide();
                $('.hideicon').show();
            
                $('#imgShow'+y).hide();
                $('#imgHide'+y).show();

                $('#body').css("height", "auto");
                //alert('footer to bottom');
                $('#body').css("padding-bottom", "30px");
                $('#footerDiv').css("bottom", "-13%");

                openSubCategory = max;
            }
        }
    } else {
        if($('.'+x+'1').is(':visible')){
            //alert('close');
            $('#imgHide'+y).hide();
            $('#imgShow'+y).show();
            $('.'+x+'1').hide();
            openSubCategory--;
            if(openSubCategory != 0){
                $('#imgShow0').show();
                $('#imgHide0').show();
            }
            if(openSubCategory == 0){
                $('#imgHide0').hide();
            }
            if(openSubCategory <= 7){
                $('#footerDiv').css("bottom", "0%");    
            }
        } else {
            //alert('open');
            $('#imgShow'+y).hide();
            $('#imgHide'+y).show();
            $('.'+x+'1').show();
            openSubCategory++;
            if(openSubCategory != 0){
                $('#imgShow0').show();
                $('#imgHide0').show();
            }
            if(openSubCategory == 0){
                $('#imgShow0').hide();
            }
            if(openSubCategory >= 8){
                $('#footerDiv').css("bottom", "-13%");  
            }
        }   
    }
    //alert('open sub count: '+openSubCategory);
}
```

I'm also confused that seeing 0 error messages and didn't work in modern browsers. Also, how to use `dataset.value`. I'm still new to this field and still learning.

Comment: here's [element.dataset documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) - it's really very simple (not that your code uses it anyway) - the surprising thing is that the code is like 99% jquery - and jquery is supposed to be browser agnostic ... if it works in IE11, it should work in real browsers too - does toggle even get called? do the click handlers get called?

Comment: @Bravo yeah I'm also confused that 0 error message and toggle buttons are literally freezing. I can toggle on but cannot turn off.'

Comment: how do you differentiate between "on" and "off"? It's not clear what you mean by "on" and "off" - have you tried stepping through your code? i.e. `debugger` statement

Comment: @Bravo I mean I can turn on the toggle (like the other toggle buttons) after turning on the toggle button, I cannot turn off.

Comment: right - I should've guessed - and you say the browser freezes, or it's just the "buttons" don't change from on to off when you want them to?

Comment: @Bravo yesyes Buttons don't change.

Comment: again, odd that a codeblock that is literally all jquery fails like that